# Use FileZilla to connect to ssh server by passing by a middle machine

Tags: ssh

To connect to my server using ssh I use FileZilla. When I'm at work I can connect to my machine directly, but when I'm at home I must connect first to another machine and then connect to my machine. Is it possible to do that with FileZilla? I mean connecting to my machine by passing through the middle machine.

Comment: Can you ping your target machine from home?

Comment: No I can't, this why I use the middle machine.

Comment: well then you need to explain a topology of the work network. It is probably because the machine you can ping has external IP address, but your target machine doesn't, only internal IP.

Comment: My machine is accessible via http port 80 from outside my company network. All other ports are closed, so to access our machines from outside we pass through a Middle machine that has access to all other machines. They don't want to open ssh port to outside for all the machines.